# Dagger Component is not created

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

Im using Hedgehog latest version with gradle 8 and kotlin gradle files.
I have AppComponent interface:

```
@Component
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        fun context(@BindsInstance context: Context) : Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

but in my application class DaggerAppComponent is not found.
My dagger dependecies:

```
val daggerVersion = "2.45"
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion")
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion")
```

plugins:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
}
```

i tried to add kotlin kapt plugin but it tels me that it's allready on classpath

```
kotlinKapt = {id = "kotlin-kapt", version.ref = "1.8.21"}
```

And there is no folder for generated files

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project after adding dependencies ?

Comment: Yes I tried to rebuild